# How to I delete an unrequired user profile property from web.config and the database?

Tags: asp.net, properties, profile

I use the default ASP.NET Profile Provider which lets me define user properties in web.config.

I now no longer want to use **one** of these user properties. I want to delete all traces of it.

I can remove the property from the list of properties in web.config however, I suspect, the stored values for this property will still be held in the aspnet_Profile table for each user.

Is there an **easy** way to clean out all traces of the data for a property that's no longer used from the aspnet_Profile table?

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the property from the config and check the aspnet_Profile table. The value is probably not deleted. You can use SQL statement to clean the part you don't want or you could try using this which came across: http://snipplr.com/view/36547/aspnet-membership-provider--remove-unwanted-profile-properties/

Backup before you experiment :)

Comment: Link was removed. You should not just link to the answer as it could be removed like it was here.